# Prove that a Bell state is invariant under the single-qubit gate acting on both qubits

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-operation

I have a Bell state ${\Psi}^{-}= \frac{1}{\sqrt2} (|01\rangle - |10\rangle).$

How can I prove that this state is invariant (up to a global phase), when doing the same unitary $U$ on each qubit?

That is, how can I show that, for all $2\times 2$ unitaries $U$, we have:

$$(U\otimes{U})|{\Psi}^{-}\rangle = e^{i\theta}|{\Psi}^{-}\rangle?$$

Actually I don’t really understand if $U$ is generic, or it’s some particular operation. Is there some data missing?

I know $U$ acts only one one qubit but the last expression acts on two qubits.

I’m really lost.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to QCSE.  This sounds like homework/coursework; you did a reasonable job of explaining the question and where you're getting stuck I think but the more generalized you can make it, the better it will be.  $U$ is a generic unitary that only acts on one qubit, but $U\otimes U$ - that is, $U$ tensored with itself - will act on two qubits.  You're asked to prove that $\vert\Psi^-\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $U\otimes U$ for any $U$.  You might want to experiment with different $U$, such as any of the Pauli gates or the Hadamard gate.

Answer (score 1):

You can find
$$U|0\rangle \otimes U|1\rangle$$
and
$$U|1\rangle \otimes U|0\rangle$$
in the standard basis, where
$$|0\rangle \equiv \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0 \end{bmatrix},\\
|1\rangle \equiv \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1 \end{bmatrix},$$
$$|01\rangle = |0\rangle \otimes |1\rangle,\\
|01\rangle = |1\rangle \otimes |0\rangle.$$
You know that a 2x2 unitary $U$ should take this form:
$$ U  = e^{i\phi/2}\begin{bmatrix}e^{i\phi_1}\cos{\theta} &  e^{i\phi_2}\sin{\theta}\\
-e^{-i\phi_2}\sin{\theta} & 
e^{-i\phi_1}\cos{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix).
Then,

- $ U|0\rangle =\\
  =e^{i\phi/2}\begin{bmatrix}e^{i\phi_1}\cos{\theta} &  e^{i\phi_2}\sin{\theta}\\
  -e^{-i\phi_2}\sin{\theta} & 
  e^{-i\phi_1}\cos{\theta}
  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0 \end{bmatrix}\\
  =
  e^{i\phi/2}\begin{bmatrix}e^{i\phi_1}\cos{\theta}\\-e^{-i\phi_2}\sin{\theta}\end{bmatrix}
  ,$
- $ U|1\rangle =\\
  =e^{i\phi/2}\begin{bmatrix}e^{i\phi_1}\cos{\theta} &  e^{i\phi_2}\sin{\theta}\\
  -e^{-i\phi_2}\sin{\theta} & 
  e^{-i\phi_1}\cos{\theta}
  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1 \end{bmatrix}\\
  =e^{i\phi/2}\begin{bmatrix}  e^{i\phi_2}\sin{\theta}\\
  e^{-i\phi_1}\cos{\theta}
  \end{bmatrix}.$

Using this,

- $U|0\rangle \otimes U|1\rangle =\\
  = e^{i\phi/2}\begin{bmatrix}e^{i\phi_1}\cos{\theta}\\-e^{-i\phi_2}\sin{\theta}\end{bmatrix} \otimes e^{i\phi/2}\begin{bmatrix}  e^{i\phi_2}\sin{\theta}\\
  e^{-i\phi_1}\cos{\theta}
  \end{bmatrix}\\
  =
  e^{i\phi}\begin{bmatrix}  e^{i\phi_1}\cos{\theta}e^{i\phi_2}\sin{\theta}\\
  e^{i\phi_1}\cos{\theta}e^{-i\phi_1}\cos{\theta}\\
  -e^{-i\phi_2}\sin{\theta}e^{i\phi_2}\sin{\theta}\\
  -e^{-i\phi_2}\sin{\theta}e^{-i\phi_1}\cos{\theta}
  \end{bmatrix}\\
  =
  e^{i\phi}\begin{bmatrix}  e^{i(\phi_1+\phi_2)}\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}\\
  \cos^2{\theta}\\
  -\sin^2{\theta}\\
  -e^{-i(\phi_2+\phi_1)}\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}
  \end{bmatrix},$
- $U|1\rangle \otimes U|0\rangle =\\
  e^{i\phi/2}\begin{bmatrix}  e^{i\phi_2}\sin{\theta}\\
  e^{-i\phi_1}\cos{\theta}
  \end{bmatrix} \otimes e^{i\phi/2}\begin{bmatrix}e^{i\phi_1}\cos{\theta}\\-e^{-i\phi_2}\sin{\theta}\end{bmatrix}\\
  =e^{i\phi} 
  \begin{bmatrix} 
  e^{i\phi_2}\sin{\theta}e^{i\phi_1}\cos{\theta}\\ 
  -e^{i\phi_2}\sin{\theta}e^{-i\phi_2}\sin{\theta}\\
  e^{-i\phi_1}\cos{\theta}e^{i\phi_1}\cos{\theta}\\
  -e^{-i\phi_1}\cos{\theta}e^{-i\phi_2}\sin{\theta}
  \end{bmatrix}\\
  =e^{i\phi} \begin{bmatrix} e^{i(\phi_1+\phi_2)}\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}\\ -\sin^2{\theta}\\\cos^2{\theta}\\-e^{-i(\phi_1+\phi_2)}\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}\end{bmatrix}.
  $
  Then,
  $$U|0\rangle \otimes U|1\rangle - U|1\rangle \otimes U|0\rangle\\
  =e^{i\phi} \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ \cos^2{\theta}+\sin^2{\theta}\\ -\sin^2{\theta}-\cos^2{\theta}\\0\end{bmatrix}\\
  =e^{i\phi} \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\ -1\\0\end{bmatrix}.
  $$
  I didn't include the normalization constant of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ in these calculations, but clearly, applying $U \otimes U$ to this Bell state results in the same state multiplied by $e^{i\phi}$.

Answer (score 1):

Any unitary matrix can be written as $SU(2)$ matrix discarding global phase. The general form for 2x2 $SU(2)$ is $\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\-b^*&a^*\end{pmatrix}$, where $a$ and $b$ are two complex number satisfying $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$, star stands for complex conjugate.

Question becomes whether $\langle \Psi|U\otimes U|\Psi\rangle$. Replace $|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} (|01\rangle - |10\rangle)$ into $\langle \Psi|U\otimes U|\Psi\rangle$, and change $\langle 0|U|0\rangle = a, \langle 0|U|1\rangle=b,\langle 1|U|0\rangle=-b^*,\langle 1|U|1\rangle=a^*$, we can get $\langle \Psi|U\otimes U|\Psi\rangle=1$ .

Your question is also refer to that the maximal entangled state remain maximal entangled with the operation of LOCC.